# output website contents to a string android code

Tags: android, web

i would like to read a website url and output the html code of the content to a string 
.After that i would like to search for urls within the string and output them to a an other string.Anyway i would like to help me only with the output of the html code to a string.
Thank  you in advance. i have the following code. Is it correct

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/");
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
String encoding = con.getContentEncoding();
encoding = encoding == null ? "UTF-8" : encoding;
String body = IOUtils.toString(in, encoding);
```

Comment: But if you only want help with getting the code in a string, and you have above code of which you say that it is correct... what more do you want then?

Comment: the above code is not working on me

Comment: well, what does it do? Does it generate an error? What do you see, and waht do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the [jericho parsing library](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html) which turned out to be very handy.
I allows you to browse the HTML tags of the document and access the tags attributes.
For example, to get all the links' urls: (please check the exact syntax in documentation)

```
Source source = new Source(new URL("http://...");
List<Element> elementList = source.getAllElements(); // loads all HTML tags in a list
    for (Element element : elementList) {
    if (element.getName().equals("A")) { // if <A> tag
    String segment = element.getContent().toString(); // will give you a string "< a href=...>...</A>
    String url = element.getAttributeValue("href"); // will return the url of the link
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the Jsoup html parser: http://jsoup.org/download
you want the .jar file. 
Once you have that, to grab the html is pretty simple. You can say

```
String html = Jsoup.connect("http://url.com").get().html();
```

To search for your url's use something to traverse the string like a normal string(Such as the Scanner class, which is simple to use). To use that you could do: (of course look in the api to understand this too, but here:)

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(html);
String links = "";
while(in.hasNext()){
    String line = in.nextLine();
    if(line.contains("yoursearchingkeyword") 
         links += line.substring(line.indexOf("http"),line.indexOf("</a>") + "\n";
}
```

The links string would have your links for you there.